# How to remove unwanted elements from a paragraph in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm parsing html content from a web page.

I need to convert this paragraph:

```
<p>Bryan Cranston was a guest on the third episode of <a href="/wiki/ALF%27s_Hit_Talk_Show" title="ALF's Hit Talk Show">ALF's Hit Talk Show</a>.
Bryan Cranston is an American actor best known for his roles as Walter White in <i>Breaking Bad</i>, for which he won three consecutive Outstanding Lead Actor in a Drama Series Emmy Awards; and as Hal, the father in <i>Malcolm in the Middle</i>.</p>
```

into this:

```
<p>Bryan Cranston was a guest on the third episode of ALF's Hit Talk Show.
Bryan Cranston is an American actor best known for his roles as Walter White in <i>Breaking Bad</i>, for which he won three consecutive Outstanding Lead Actor in a Drama Series Emmy Awards; and as Hal, the father in <i>Malcolm in the Middle</i>.</p>
```

As you can see, I'm just keeping the i elements, and removing any other elements.

I'm stuck and this is what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/JyxL4/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are using an each but I think is necessary, then you can use method `.unwrap()` to delete link tag but keep inner HTML.
 try this:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    $(this).find('a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

or more easily

```
$('p a').contents().unwrap();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JyxL4/4/)

Comment: `$('p a').contents().unwrap();` should do

Comment: sure but into the example OP uses an each and I have keep it, well I add this solution thanks for the tip @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 1):

```
$( 'p *' ).not( 'i' ).contents().unwrap();
```

or

```
$('p *').not( 'i' ).each(function(){
    $( this ).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JyxL4/8/)